# MySQL & PHP load more then 1000 items makes browser freeze

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a small issue with loading my data from database. I have table with 1150 rows, and I would love to show them on single page.

Here's my `SELECT`:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id as id, name as name FROM table") or die;
```

Here's my PHP:

```
while ($zaznam = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
extract($zaznam);
echo $id ."-". $name;
endwhile;
```

It works good, but page is loading about 10 sec and browser is frozen during the SELECT.

Is there any chance to speed this up, or show only part of items and on scroll load next and so on?

Comment: What are you using for your web server? What operating system? If this is a local machine, try a proper server - a 256M Linux VPS from a decent provider, for example. This should load much more quickly than the times you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hit the nail on the head. Printing this in pages is advisable. Add a `LIMIT` to your SQL query. Also, don't `echo` in your loop. Instead, append to a variable then echo at the end.

Comment: Wow! If I put echo out of loop it's on about 1-2 secs. This helped me a lot. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

the best solution i see, is to use infinitescroll with ajax request.

you have many ways to do it, look on jquery or angularjs solutions, but it's more complicated.

Otherwise you can improve your computer performances, and it will be faster.