# Browser freeze when retrieving a lot data using php & mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Good day, I have billing system that only works when the data in the database is not much but when I import a full items of data into the table the browser freeze and takes a long time to retrieve what I search, I have tried to add limit to my query as suggested here:

[MySQL & PHP load more then 1000 items makes browser freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715196/mysql-php-load-more-then-1000-items-makes-browser-freeze)

but the problem with that is, it does not retrieved all data from the table as its limited.

is there any other workaround that I can try?

Here is my piece of code:

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM medications ";
    $result = $con->query($query);
?> 
<select id="disease"  style="width: 40%;" name="disease" required="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="medications" class="date-picker form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" data-rel="chosen">
    <option value="">Select Disease</option>
    <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['ICD10'] ?>"><?php echo $row['diagnosis']; ?> </option> 
    <?php } ?> 
</select>
```

Comment: please show us some php codes and database CREATE strings and SELECT QUERIES so we can help you...

Comment: apologies 

i have included them now

Answer (score 0):

If your browser itself freezes, meaning that the whole browser becomes unresponsive, it simply means that your browser itself is running out of capacity (likely due to low RAM on your 'puter). There's not much you can do about that in PHP/MySQL itself. Some things you can try:

- Optimize your HTML output to make it less heavy to parse where possible.
- Buffer up your HTML and output in one go in the end, instead of echoing incrementally.
- Load your data on-demand with the help of AJAX, instead of blurting out everything in one page-load. (Possibly remove older sections when new data is loaded.)
- Review how your CSS and jQuery(?) work. I see there's something going on with your `data-toggle` attribute. Dynamically applying a ton of events/classes will lead to issues.

And if by "freeze" you mean that the script takes a long time to execute... I see you query for all fields in the table, `SELECT *`. You can make it lighter for MySQL and your server RAM by only selecting the fields you actually require (`SELECT ICD10, diagnosis ...`). <del>Also consider adding in pagination and using `LIMIT` in your query.</del> (*Sorry:* That's not relevant here, since you're using the data for `<select>` options.) There's not a whole lot that can be said about your PHP here, but do look around and see if there are possible bottlenecks outside the code snipped you've posted.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, but it cant be the computer RAM nor its processing capabilities because i tried it on several computers and some even better than mine but the same issue still occurred.

Also when i use LIMIT it works just fine but problem is it does not show or retrieve all data as its limited

Comment: So does "freeze" mean "whole browser becomes unresponsive" -- or "page takes a long time to load", but the browser still responds to actions, ie. you can still scroll, switch tabs etc.? If it's just the latter, then see the second part of my reply. If you use `LIMIT`, you'd of course use in the context of pagination -- that is, split your data across several pages, limiting each page to as much as your server can handle.

Comment: yes the whole browser becomes unresponsive and it also actually takes a bit longer to load the page, but when i use limit on the query it works just fine the problem is now when i want it to use the full database not omitting anything out

Comment: If the whole browser becomes unresponsive, then your HTML + javascripts etc. are overloading it. If it happens even with more powerful 'puters, that simply means it's way over the top. ^_^ Humor yourself and open up your Task Manager and/or the browser's developer tools and see what sort of a burden you're creating. Also, how many rows are we talking about with your "full database"?

Comment: yes even i very powerful machines the same issue is there

its 70000 rows with 5 columns

Comment: yeah its definatly overloading it.. it consumes a whole lot of memory when i run it

Comment: 70000 rows with 5 columns (of which 2 are used here) means you're trying to push in over 6 MB in just the `<option>...` lines... Now that's harsh enough just with plain HTML, and then if you apply styles and/or javascript to each on top of it, that'll kill the best of browsers and computers... You're going to have to rethink your approach to accessing your database.

Comment: It would work a bit lighter if you changed from `select` to `input type="radio"`, and put those into a scrolling div to keep it from reaching to infinity. With a `select`, the browser's waiting to load all the options before it can render that one element, while radio-ticks would be individually output. And gosh, I can't imagine dealing with a dropdown with 70000 options even if it loaded!

Comment: the dropdown i made it searcheble to able to filter data as you search, so from radio how im i going to be able to search?

Comment: If you remove the search feature, will that help the browser not freeze? As for how you'd do that with radio-buttons, simply attach the same feature to the parent-element (probably `div`) of the radio inputs, and filter as necessary.

Comment: Now for more alternatives: If you don't actually need all the data for anything else aside searching, why not simply start with a blank slate and use the search with AJAX to query the database for matching substrings (say, after the 3rd char of input), `LIKE 'sic%'` etc. and then populate your `select`, or radios, or input-with-datalist, or whatever else with the result. Somehow or other, you really need to narrow down the data you bring to your page.